# Using Listbox in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `listbox` control. I have created an `ItemTemplate` for this `listbox` which has two controls within it.

1. Toggle Button
2. Listbox Control

Structure

```
<Listbox x:Key="Listbox1" ItemTemplate={StaticResource ListBox1ParentItemTemplate}>

</Listbox>

<Datatemplate x:Key="ListBox1ParentItemTemplate">
    <ToggleButton></ToggleButton>
    <Listbox x:Key="Listbox1" ItemTemplate={StaticResource ListBox2ParentItemTemplate}>
    </Listbox>
</Datatemplate>

<Datatemplate x:Key="ListBox2ParentItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=@Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</Datatemplate>
```

Basically the `Listbox2` is a `CheckedListbox`. My requirement is as follows
1. Bind the `ToggleButton` to `Listbox1 SelectedItem` i.e if 4 item is selected in `Listbox1` then the togglebutton of 4th item should get checked automatically and other togglebutton should get unchecked.
2. If the `ToggleButton` is checked then all checkboxes in `Listbox2` should automatically selected. Also if one of the checkboxes in `Listbox2` is unselected then `ToogleButton` should get unchecked automatically. (This functionality is similar to `TreeNode` and childnode functionality. If parentnode is checked then all childnodes get selected and if one of the childnode is unselected parentnode should get unselected).

Answer (score 1):

Sample code will help us understand your problem better.

Looks like you are trying to add some business logic on to the UI, Try creating proper ViewModel and then Bind it to the control so that the calculations can be done at the ViewModel side and based on your logic you can update the UI- (INotifyPropertyChanged)

The ViewModel will be having a Bool property(Bind to ToggleButton) which changes according to the other 3 bool(which binds to the 4 Checkboxes). At any setter call inside the ViewModel has to recalculate(It will be a boolean AND operation) the entire Properties again. Since CheckBox binding mode is defaulted to TwoWay, it will be very easy to implement.